# Card layout like Google Play usic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Click the layout, show translucent orange layer. 
In the layout, there have buttons, button can be clicked, but NOT need to show the orange layer.
How to achieve?
Is this right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="position1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- the orange layer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_translucent_orange"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and the selector_translucent_orange.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/trans_orange" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems you need a selector to your linear layout. If that is true

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_translucent_orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="position1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I mean like the new Youtube app card layout.